# Admob cordova plugin in ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob, cordova-plugins

I am implementing Admob using this cordova plugin:
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

I have added the plugin and have this in my .config of an ionic application:

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider, $sceDelegateProvider){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    if(AdMob) 
      AdMob.createBanner({
        adId:'admob-banner-id-entered-here', 
        position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
        autoShow:true
      });
  });
}
```

Build and test in testflight and no banner ad showing.
I have tried Admob, window.plugin.AdMob, window.Admob, and also injecting $cordovaAdMob and using $cordovaAdMob but no Banner appears.

How do I get this plugin to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i implemented something like this in ionic1 with the same plugin.
In a controller of a view put this.

```
if (AdMob) var adbMob = AdMob.createBanner({
                adId: ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/9375997553, // Test ID
                isTesting: true, //For testing advices...
                autoShow: true
            });
```

This works :D

Greetings

Comment: Thanks will try, did you have to inject Admob into the controller or do anything else to get this to work for you?

Comment: I dont inject any(in controller and module(app.js)) , the AdMob is a plugin include in ngCordova (inject ngCordova if dont have)

Comment: Have tried your suggestion and many others from searching and for some reason still cannot get Admob to work. Can anyone provide a current working example of using Admob within Ionic1 that has been tested recently and is fully functional, thanks

Comment: You have ngcordova injected in the ionic proyect?

Comment: I am building the app using ionic framework within telerik app builder platform.. cordova is installed by default and the AdMob plugin is installed successfully into the project. All other cordova plugins are referenced by placing a $cordova before the plugin name and work fine, however as mentioned above using the usage reference here https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/AdMob-Pro or by injecting $cordovaAdMob or using any of the above window.AdMob, window.plugins.AdMob just do not work for this plugin. Last build I tried injecting $cordovaAdMob ...

Comment: into the controller and referencing all with $cordovaAdMob and I get a blank banner ad at the top (although the code says to open it at the bottom) and the app is frozen, thats the best I have achieved so far with this issue

Comment: i will try test this demo https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/AdMob-Pro-DemoApp in your device/emulator.

Comment: Hey dherediat, thanks so much for your assistance on this.. finally got it operational.. changed the plugin to https://github.com/sunnycupertino/cordova-plugin-admob-simple and using var Admob = window.plugins.AdMob ads came up straight away.. not sure why I had issues with the pro plugin but finally operational.. thanks again